# Ngrok - Action Mailbox send me a 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, ngrok, action-mailbox

I want to receive and parse emails from my Rails application using Action Mailbox. In local, everything works fine.

I then wanted to try sending email from my Gmail account and needed to set up Sendgrid and Ngrok. To do so, I've followed the configuration from here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/action_mailbox_basics.html

When I send an email, I have the following error in ngrok **403 Forbidden**. But when I check the web interface, I can see the email.

After looking on the internet, I've added to application_mailbox.rb :

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

and to development.rb :

```
config.hosts << /[a-z0-9]+\.ngrok\.io/
```

But nothing works. I get the same error every time.
Does anyone know what can I do to fix this issue ?

I feel that the problem may be with the URL with the password I've configured Sendgrid with but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I was using http instead of https in my sendgrid's url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).